# from transition table to regular expression

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So i have this transition table and i want to turn it into a regular expression. how do i go about doing that? i found this [link](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/threads/436423/code-to-produce-regular-expression-from-transition-table), but i don't know what they are trying to do here.

so here is the table.

```
        a    b
    ----------
    0|  2    0
    1|  1    1
    2|  1    3
    3|  2    3
```

And here is what its asking for:
Suppose the above machine is a Moore machine with starting state 0, and state 3 is the only accept state. Write a regular expression that describes the set of strings accepted by the Moore machine defined above.

I have b* abb* aab*
but i have a feeling this is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But you are kindda close.. You need to carry the (ab)* and the b* that left you in the 3rd node. So is like b*ab as you have but then keep track of those two paths to be on the 3rd node..and use the kleene star to do the combinations on those paths.

Comment: So what process do you follow to get the right answer? do you mind sharing that with me? Because i don't really understand what you are saying.

Comment: I do not mind, the process i follow is what i tried to say.if you paint the automata you would see the paths that left you in the 3rd node. So, first as you start in 0node you would probably stay a little while in it (b*) or you try to go to the 2node (b*a) then you would like to go to 3node so you must have,at least, a "b" so you have(at this point)something like b*ab(that you had in your expression). But in this point you can return to 2 node with "a" and then get back to 3 node with "b" that is a (ab)* or you can stay on 3 node with b*..So you would have like $b^*ab(b^* \cup (ab)^*)^*$